# $wpdb->insert not working, last_query doesn't show insert "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I run `$wpdb->insert($table, $data)` where data is an array with column_name => value and the insert is not working. I tried `$wpdb->last_query` and something bizarre comes back:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `table_im_trying_to_insert`
```

Why is the last query not my insert?

Comment: This code was working fine until recent update from WP 4.2. I tracked the problem to two columns that are not different from the rest; however when I exclude those two columns the insert works.

Comment: What do you mean by 'is not working'? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently with the new WP update if you try to insert into a VARCHAR column and the column length is less than what you are trying to insert it just won't work. Prior to this update it will insert it but trim off the excess characters.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on this for like 3 days, if ( wordpressknowledgelevel > before) wordpresshate++;

Comment: well in my case the length of the data was greater than the size of the column, clearly I wasn't inserting the correct data in that column.

Comment: Thanks. Saved my time.

Comment: If I could upvote you more, I would. I don't get why Wordpress tries to abstract so much from devs - if the column is too long, just tell us. Don't respond with a non-sensical thing like this. </rant>

Comment: I had to read the answer a few times to understand it - it just was not stated the way I would have (nothing against the posted by any means) but I understand it now.

Comment: Thanks, this applies not only to VARCHAR but also to TEXT - in my case I needed to change from TEXT to MEDIUMTEXT.

Comment: Hey my friend, you saved my life! :) I am debugging the code since yesterday for this fu..in error.

Comment: Ohh, thankx , I thought my site is getting hacked... but learned new sql because of this error SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `table`...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, thats some very awkward behavior from wordpress. I rather have an error than this.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I changed the field type from `VARCHAR` to `TEXT`, but it still didn't work. Finally, I found the table with collation of `utf8_general_ci` does not support emoji, so I removed all the emojis from the content then it works.